# regex.sub unexpectedly modifying the substituting string with some kind of encoding?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a path string "...\\JustStuff\\2017GrainHarvest_GQimagesTestStand\\..." that I am inserting into an existing text file in place of another string.  I compile a regex pattern and find bounding text to get the location to insert, and then use regex.sub to replace it.  I'm doing something like this...

```
with open(imextXML, 'r') as file:
    filedata = file.read()
redirpath = re.compile("(?<=<directoryPath>).*(?=</directoryPath>)", re.ASCII)
filedatatemp = redirpath.sub(newdir,filedata)
```

The inserted text is messed up though, with "\\20" being replaced with "\x8" and "\\"  replaced with "\" (single slash)

i.e.
"...\\JustStuff\\2017GrainHarvest_GQimagesTestStand\\..." becomes
"...\\JustStuff\x817GrainHarvest_GQimagesTestStand\..."

What simple thing am I missing here to fix it?

### Update:

to break this down even further to copy and paste to reproduce the issue...

```
t2 = r'\JustStuff\2017GrainHarvest_GQimagesTestStand\te'
redirpath = re.compile("(?<=<directoryPath>).*(?=</directoryPath>)", re.ASCII)
temp = r"<directoryPath>aasdfgsdagewweags</directoryPath>"
redirpath.sub(t2,temp)
```

produces...

```
>>'<directoryPath>\\JustStuff\x817GrainHarvest_GQimagesTestStand\te</directoryPath>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define the string that you want to insert, prefix it with an `r` to indicate that it is a [raw string literal](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals):

```
>>> rex = re.compile('a')
>>> s = 'path\\with\\2017'
>>> sr = r'path\\with\\2017'
>>> rex.sub(s, 'ab')
'path\\with\x817b'
>>> rex.sub(sr, 'ab')
'path\\with\\2017b'
```

Comment: OK...hmm, newdir does look like "sr" in your example...with double slashes. (I had to correct my post since double slashes in quotes where showing up in the post as a single slash).  It's only after i do the re.sub that it is incorrect and looks like "s" in your example.

Comment: @user3496060 I see, then you should probably define the double backslashed version as a raw string as well

Comment: Sry -- just saw that :-)